Is there a way to print these optl logs to files?
In mentioned code i am trying to save these logs periodically to txt files.
I have referred and checked docs but unable to find it. These logs must be saved every 30mins. Adding the files for flask api and project structure
Main.py
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import ConsoleMetricExporter
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.trace_exporter import OTLPSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.logs import LoggerProvider, LoggingHandler
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import SERVICE_NAME, Resource
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.flask import FlaskInstrumentor
from app import create_app
from app.api import api

app = create_app('config/config.yaml')

FlaskInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)

resource = Resource(attributes={SERVICE_NAME: "sample-flask-app"})

tracer_provider = TracerProvider(resource=resource)
span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(OTLPSpanExporter())
tracer_provider.add_span_processor(span_processor)

metrics_provider = MeterProvider(resource=resource)
metrics_provider.add_metric_reader(ConsoleMetricExporter())

logging_provider = LoggerProvider(resource=resource)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(LoggingHandler(logging_provider))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("application_logger")
trace_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    app.config['logging']['traces_log_dir'] + "/traces.log", when="m", interval=app.config['logging']['log_file_interval']
)
metric_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    app.config['logging']['metrics_log_dir'] + "/metrics.log", when="m", interval=app.config['logging']['log_file_interval']
)
app_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    app.config['logging']['application_log_dir'] + "/app.log", when="m", interval=app.config['logging']['log_file_interval']
)

trace_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
metric_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.getLogger("opentelemetry").addHandler(trace_handler)
logger.addHandler(app_handler)

app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix="/api")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        host=app.config['app']['host'],
        port=app.config['app']['port'],
        debug=app.config['app']['debug']
    )

App/api.py
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
import time

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    return jsonify({"status": "OK", "timestamp": time.time()}), 200

@api.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    data = request.json
    result = {"received_data": data, "timestamp": time.time()}
    return jsonify(result), 201

App/init.py
from flask import Flask
from yaml import safe_load

def create_app(config_path):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    with open(config_path, 'r') as file:
        config = safe_load(file)
    app.config.update(config)
    return app

Requirements
Flask
PyYAML
opentelemetry-api
opentelemetry-sdk
opentelemetry-instrumentation-flask

What is your actual question? Right now, you have provided a very vague question in your title and a bunch of code. What do you want to achieve exactly? What works with your code, what does not work? Please provide all error messages and stack traces. Please be specific. Please provide the additional details in your question. You can [edit] it with the link below it.
